# Calling jQuery function from the server

Tags: jquery, server-side, serverside-javascript

I have a web system which collects measurements data.
Those inputs comes from a mobile device (iPhone with a custom website).
I would like to show a message at the admin's web site each time the server gets an input from a mobile device.
The message mechanism will use *jQuery.Gritter* to show them.

My question: how can I call the jQuery function from the server?
I think I can't use `RegisterStartupScript()` nor `RegisterClientScriptBlock()` since the web page is performing any postback.

Answer (score 0):

Have a listener on the server side which checks for updates to a page/database, and have the mobile website use AJAX to submit a change whenever it's relevant.

Comment: The server knows when the mobile website inserts a new input, but how can it call the jQuery function at the client side?

Comment: When the server knows, the listener will usually be in jQuery, meaning you can activate more of it when it's relevant

Comment: Can you provide a code sample or a link of how to implement such a listener in jQuery?